# PHP SDK Adaptative Payment How to set Quantity if not embed

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

We use Paypal PHP SDK adaptative payment service to process payments in our site as we receive the payment, take a commission and send the remaining to the listing owner.

We got the PayRequest and the SetPaymentOptions working. The problem is the ReceiverOptions InvoiceData accordingly with the documentation only work with embed pay flow.

So how am I supposed to pass quantity to be paid if I am not using embed pay flow but I need adaptative payment because of the commission we take?

Comment: After lots of research I figured that there is no way to pass quantity and item info to the pay review window if I am not using embed payflow. As an alternative I decided to set all the invoice info so the user has those details in the paypal account and for the pay review window I would use the 'memo' field. However the 'memo' field don't see to show in the normal (not embed) flow either. Can anyone confirm?